# How to Connect Django with Python based Crawler machine?

Tags: python, django, web-crawler

Good day folks

Recently, I made a python based web crawler machine that *scrapes*_ some news ariticles and django web page that collects search title and url from users.

But I do not know how to connect the python based crawler machine and django web page together, so I am looking for the any good resources that I can reference.

If anyone knows the resource that I can reference,
Could you guys share those?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more information about the environment? Are those two programs going to run on the same computer or on two different servers or maybe containers?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your crawler? which library & framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are numerous ways you could do this.**

You could directly integrate them together. Both use Python, so the scraper would just be written as part of Django.

You could have the scraper feed the data to a database and have Django read from that database.

You could build an API from the scraper to your Django implementation.

There are quite a few options for you depending on what you need.